# Read from external file, skip lines after a match, print and exit

Tags: awk, posix

POSIX awk wizards, I need your help! The question may seem trivial to
you at first glance, however, let me describe my intents in greater
detail.

I have been working on a self-contained POSIX awk program, finished it
by 95% but can’t figure out the correct way of doing something that I’m
going to show you in just a moment.

## Solution in POSIX sh

First of, here’s the solution in POSIX sh of what I’m trying to achieve:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
key=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)  # results in 2022-08-04
while read -r line; do
  awk -v key=$key '$0 ~ key {
      for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            getline current
      print current
  }' "$line"
done < /tmp/awk.data
```

As shown in the snippet above, I’m reading one line at a time from
`awk.data` file, invoke awk at each iteration, search for a line that
matches `key` pattern, and if it does, run a `for` loop, skipping 9
lines and then printing the final one.

Here is the contents of said `awk.data` file:

```
$ cat /tmp/awk.data
/tmp/sample-001.html
/tmp/sample-002.html
/tmp/sample-003.html
# <...>
/var/log/sample-787.html
/var/log/sample-788.html
```

## Attempts to solve the problem in POSIX awk

This is a small part I’m trying to implement in my POSIX awk program,
and here is what I’ve tried so far — to no avail, however.

```c
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    date = getdate()
    data = "/tmp/awk.data"

    # <...>

    read(data)
}

function getdate() {
    cmd = "date +%Y-%m-%d"
    cmd | getline date
    close(cmd)
    return date
}

function read(data) {
    cmd = "cat" " " data
    while (cmd | getline line)
        parse(line)
    close(cmd)
}

function parse(file) {
    cmd = "cat" " " file
    while (cmd | getline line) {
        if (line ~ date) {
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                getline current
            print current
        }
    }
    close(cmd)
}
```

The `read` function reads each line outputted by `cat`, that is,
`/tmp/sample-001.html`, `/tmp/sample-002.html`, etc. and passes it to
`parse` — another function that shall parse each file and produce the
desired output.

This is the first attempt of mine to use the `while` loop on each
processed line and then check whether current line matches the pattern
defined by `date` variable; if it does, start a `for` loop that skips 9
lines and prints the final one. This is quite possibly *very*
inefficient, but the program runs, though it just loops forever and
prints nothing. I‘m stuck completely!

To reiterate, *my awk program is not going to take any arguments*, thus
reading from external file from within awk is paramount in this case.

Many thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Note that in `cmd | getline`, `awk` starts `sh` in s child process to interpret the shell code stored in `cmd`, so if your intent was to remove `sh` from the equation, you can't use `system`, `print | cmd` or `cmd | getline` in `awk`.

Comment: Which version of the POSIX standard are you targetting? Note that the next version will support [`nextfile`](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=607) (already supported by most implementations) which can help with performance.

Comment: Also note that POSIX doesn't specify the shebang mechanism  (you can't use a shebang reliably with standard awk anyway) nor the location of the `awk` utility.

Comment: Hello, Stéphane! I’m completely stuck and have no idea how to port the code from the POSIX sh snippet to awk to achieve the same functionality without feeding awk any arguments from the command line. As for the POSIX specification, I assume any would suffice, even [the latest one](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). In other words, the script needs to run on *BSD systems without any issues. To sum up, compatibility with (Open|Free)BSD is mandatory, and support for arcane systems may not be as important.

Comment: By trying to do this using a shebang to call awk you're making everything harder than it has to be. Obviously calling awk multiple times in a loop is the wrong approach, but why not have your shell script call awk once and pass it arguments to do everything in a single call?

Comment: If you ask a new question and include concise, testable sample input and expected output we can show you the right way to write a Unix command to do what you want and it will not involve calling awk from a shebang, nor will it it involve calling awk multiple times from a shell loop, nor will it involve awk spawning subshells to execute other commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  ARGC = 1
  while ((getline file < "awk.data") > 0)
    ARGV[ARGC++] = file
  "date +%Y-%m-%d" | getline date
}
FNR == 1 {
  line_to_print = 0
}
line_to_print {
  if (FNR == line_to_print) {print; nextfile}
  next
}
index($0, date) {line_to_print = FNR + 10}
```

`nextfile` is not POSIX yet, but will be in the next version. The code above still works in `awk` implementations that don't support `nextfile` (in which case it's still valid code, but that does nothing).

Note that POSIX doesn't specify the shebang mechanism nor the path of the `awk` utility. `#! /path/to/awk -f` shebangs are not reliable as upon invocation, a `that-script -x` becomes `/path/to/awk -f /path/to/that-script -x`, where the `-x` could be treated as an option by `awk` (and an argument like `'-eBEGIN{system("reboot")}'` would reboot with the GNU implementation of `awk` for instance.

In `"date..." | getline date`, `awk` does invoke `sh` to invoke the command line, so that does not remove `sh` from the equation. `awk` cannot run commands without the help of `sh`. GNU `awk` can format the current date but it's not standard. You can get the current date as epoch time with `srand()` POSIXly (but OpenBSD is not POSIX in that regard), but then converting that to YYYy-MM-DD format in the user's timezone would be quite difficult. `perl` would likely be a much better language than `awk` here if the point is to avoid `sh`.

Beware that if the lines of `awk.data` are in the `foo=bar.html` format, `awk` will treat them as variable assignment instead of paths of files to process. If that may be the case, you could sanitise those path in the BEGIN statement with:

```
function sanitise(path) {
  if (path != "" && path !~ /^\//)
    return "./" path
  else
    return path
}
```

(and use `ARGV[ARGC++] = sanitise(file)` instead of `ARGV[ARGC++] = file`).

Also beware that `getline file`, contrary to `read -r line` doesn't strip leading and trailing spaces and tabs from the input line. If you wanted them to be stripped you'd have to do it manually:

```
getline file
sub(/^[ \t]*/, "", file)
sub(/[ \t]*$/, "", file)
```

For instance.

Another difference with your `while read` loop is that if the last line is not delimited, it would still be processed by `awk`, but discarded by a `while read` `sh` loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, Stéphane, your solution works as a charm! `reboot` is usually located in `/usr/sbin/` and normally requires root privileges upon execution as it’s not explicitly whitelisted in `/etc/sudoers` file on my Debian machine, for example. Interesting point about shebangs nonetheless, thank you so much for sharing the knowledge!

Comment: As for invoking shell from within awk to get hold of some input, I’m totally fine by that and by no means an awk purist! Much obliged for the `sanitise` function! The hacker in you truly shows as you spot non-trivial things that may be easily abused by competent people.  Wonderful and helpful answer, thank you so much once again.

Comment: @vaeu, `reboot` was just an example, intended to be striking enough but not as damaging as say `rm -rf ~`. It's not uncommon these days for `reboot` to be allowed to regular users as long as they're logged in locally to the system via polkit.